# Issue with jQuery.ajax call to web service

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I am Developing a Registration Form in ASP.NET in Which I am using client side scripting. So I used jQuery.ajax method to POST all fields' data to server through a ASP.NET Web-Service. But when I execute the Jquery.ajax method it calls error function. I tried to debug it using Firebug in Firefox. It showed error 500 Internal Server Error. Now what I assume is that to Insert Data into a WebService I need to use a POST method and similarly I need a function on Server Side inside Webservice which can be invoked using POST method. I am providing few snippets of code to illustrate what I have done.

My client script:

```
//My Client Side Function
function registerUser()
{
    var User = {
      FirstName:$get("txtFirstName").value,
      LastName:$get("txtLastName").value
      .
      .
      //and so on....This way I creat my json object to POST on server
      };

      //jQuery to POST Data
      jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"Service/UserRegistration.asmx/InsertUser",
        data:User,
        success:notifyUser,
        error:setErrorField
      });

}

//Function for Success Complition
function notifyUser(msg)
{
       alert("Registration Successfull");
}
```

My web Service on the server:

```
//My C# Web Service Logic
[WebMethod]
public void InsertUser(User use)
{
      FreeUser us = new FreeUser();
      us.FirstName = use.FirstName;
      .
      .
      //and so on
}
```

Now what I suppose is that POST method requires `WebInvoke` class as attribute. How do I make a method which can be called by JavaScript? I may have to use `WebInvoke` for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have ASP.NET AJAX available on the server-side (ASP.NET 2.0 + ASP.NET AJAX Extensions v1.0 or ASP.NET 3.5+), I've found that the easiest way to do it is to use JSON between the client and server-side.  You'll just need to add the [ScriptService] attribute to your service and then use this form for calling the service:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

For more info, see the full post here:  http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

In order to provide a JavaScript object as you are in that example code, you'll also need to [use JSON.Stringify to generate an appropriate JSON string to pass to the server-side](http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're submitting a JSON object, add the following option to `$.ajax`:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```